# Image drag and drop (WPF Window)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop

I need to drag and drop from `Image` `img2` to `Image` `img1`. That means that I want to copy `img2` when I drag it on `img1`. Program is starting, but destination `Image` `img1` is not changing after I drag `Image` `img2` on it.

> How to solve this problem to make it work ?

**My code below:**

*XAML:*

```
<Canvas Name="va">
        <Image Name="img1" Height="100" Width="100" AllowDrop="True" Drop="img1_Drop" />
        <Image Name="img2" Height="100" Width="100" Source="Resources/eye.bmp" 
               MouseLeftButtonDown="img2_MouseLeftButtonDown" AllowDrop="True" />
</Canvas>
```

*C# code:*

```
private void img2_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Image image = e.Source as Image;
    DataObject data = new DataObject(typeof(ImageSource), image.Source);
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(image, data, DragDropEffects.All);
}

private void img1_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Image imageControl = (Image)sender;
    if ((e.Data.GetData(typeof(ImageSource)) != null))
    {
        ImageSource image = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ImageSource)) as ImageSource;
        imageControl = new Image() { Width = 100, Height = 100, Source = image };
        img1 = imageControl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind that in WPF, it is a `Window`, not a `Form`.

Comment: Here is good example https://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/drag-and-drop-files-to-wpf-application-and-asynchronously-upload-to-asp-net-web-api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning `img1 = imageControl;` will not add a new Image control to the Canvas.

You should instead simply assign the `Source` property of `img1`:

```
img1.Source = (ImageSource)e.Data.GetData(typeof(ImageSource));
```

Comment: Plus 1... How easy it is to bypass the restriction :)